# Can $\prod_{l = 1}^L \prod_{m=1}^M \text{P}_r(X\leq\gamma_{th})$ be written as $[F_X(\gamma_{th})]^{L\cdot M}$, where $F_X(\cdot)$ is CDF of $X$?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, products, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am dealing with big Pi notation as shown below:

\begin{align}
P = \prod_{l = 1}^L \prod_{m=1}^M \text{P}_r(X\leq\gamma_{th}) \tag1
\end{align}

where $X$ is a random variable. And all others are constant.

My query is

> Can we write eq (1) as shown by eq (2).
> \begin{align}
> P = [F_X(\gamma_{th})]^{L\cdot M} \tag2
> \end{align}
> where $F_X(\cdot)$ is CDF of $X$?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is $P_r$? Do you consider some family of probabilities?

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your response. Yes its probability.

Comment: So you consider $R$ probabilities $P_r$ for $r=1,2,\ldots,R$? Then what is $F_X?$ For which $r$ it's  $F_X(t) = P_r(X\leq t)$?

Comment: I had updated the notations in the equations...Pls check it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Put $a:=\text{P}_r(X\leq\gamma_{th})$. In $\prod_{m=1}^M a$ we have a product of $M$ the same factors $a$. Therefore $\prod_{m=1}^M a = a^M$. The same is with the outer product.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for the answer.